# Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm-install

I am start learn to react native i am getting this when i have run my project build successfully but when open the app and get this error

I have to run my react native sample project like react-native init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject

npm insatll

react-native run-android

> and getting this errorerror: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve
>   module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from
>   `/Users/macbookpro/AwesomeProject/index.js`: Module
>   `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the
>   Haste module map`

before i have complete my all react native setup from this link

**https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html**

I am use macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: i have got my answer npm install --save @babel/runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue can be fixed by using

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

or

```
yarn add @babel/runtime
```

The issue is still open at this moment and will hopefully get resolved in new release.
For now,you can keep babel/runtime in devDependencies, but if you want to build a release build with this version of react-native, you need to put @babel/runtime in dependencies.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21310) for more details